# How can i reduce the size of a pdf file generated from ssrs with .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services

I am generating a PDF file from SSRS and sending mail to the Vendor. but when the file size is bigger than the email quota size, the mail is not forwarding. I need help to compress the file to reduce the size of file. Please advice me. following is the sample code.

```
string FileName = "SomeFileName_" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", DateTime.Now) + ".pdf";
string DirPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Files/XXXX");
string FilePath = Path.Combine(DirPath, FileName);
string strTargetURL = GlobalParameters.SSRSBaseUrl + "/XXXXXX/rptRDLName&User_ID=" + CurrentUserData.UserId + "&P_ENQUIRY_HD_ID=" + EnquiryID + "&rc:LinkTarget=_blank&rc:Parameters=False&rs:Format=PDF&rs:ClearSession=true";
try
{
    ReportViewer objReportViewer = new ReportViewer();
    objReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
    objReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new CustomReportCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerPwd"], "BSM");
    objReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
    SSRSWebClient client = new SSRSWebClient();
    client.DownloadFileBinary(FilePath, strTargetURL);
    if (new FileInfo(FilePath).Exists)
    {     
        //............
        //Send mail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Font used in your SSRS report is standard - like arial (or whatever is the standard default).  makes a HUGE difference.  For ours - gone from 200k to 12k.  Also, make sure the images are properly optimized on the report.

FONT: Arial; 9pt; Default; Default; Default

Make sure the image is properly optimized - use something like Yahoo SmushIT

Comment: I am using Verdana font family my current file size is 317KB; but I changed it to Aril now its size is 325kb.